# Will EEVEE eliminate the need for cycles and rendering?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, eevee-render-engine

So I have been seeing a lot lately about EEVEE, and even though it is in early development it still seems really powerful. What I'm interested in is will it just eliminate the need for having cycles and rendering your scene?

Given the fact that everything is rendered in real time I see cycles and waiting for things to render becoming obsolete.

Comment: Simple answer. No. They are completely different things. But. It's always about your needs.

Comment: You can expect it to replace the internal render engine but cycles will remain.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. EEVEE will not replace cycles.

If you want accurate renders, cycles will still be your renderer. Cycles is a ray tracer, so it simulates individual rays of light your scene.

EEVEE uses approximations on the behavior of light and will not be as accurate, however is much faster.

For some projects (such as low-poly renders or stylized works), EEVEE could replace cycles, but when it comes to photorealism, cycles will still be the champion.

Comment: I would use weaker wording as Cycles being 'accurate' or 'photoreal'. I see what you mean and I am nitpicking, but put into perspective with commercial solutions Cycles is not there quite yet to be worthy be put alongside those words:) I would tag as photoreal Maxwell and Indigo: https://www.behance.net/gallery/53917965/LENSES-TEST

Comment: Recommended reading: [**Cycles vs Eevee, 15 limitations on real time rendering**](https://cgcookie.com/articles/blender-cycles-vs-eevee-15-limitations-of-real-time-rendering)