# How do I limit gloss/reflection to only intense sources such as a light source?

Tags: materials, node-editor

Using cycles,

I'm making big cartoon eyes lenses, I want them to have the light shine off them but little else.

Problem: Everything is reflected off the lens making the color of the iris and pupil look washed out in a bright setting or have it set more transparent but the shine gets too faded.

I thought maybe a toon shader for the eye shine connected with a transparent but I'm relatively new to cycles nodes so I can't figure this one out yet.

Comment: Under what render engine are you trying to do this? Cycles material properties can't depend on render results, that would be impossible to achieve without post processing. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86775/make-light-paths-only-pass-through-non-emitted-areas/86787#86787

Comment: @LukeD I've updated the question.

Comment: @LukeD I'm just at the experimental stage just throwing some light and shapes to bounce off. For now I'm testing what I can do with nodes and using what I learn to design the look of my characters.

Comment: @EricHuelin It's not possible with node setup, but if you want I can show you how to setup scene and other objects to achieve this effect.

Comment: @LukeD Maybe when Eevee gets added to Blender it might give me more options. Blender render is just not cutting it for me. Thanks for your offer.

Comment: EEVEE will not help you with such tasks. It's only viewport engine and for things like creating materials and such it's useless or in better wording - irrelevant. Check here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79568/whats-the-purpose-of-eevee-engine/79573 and here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87923/will-eevee-eliminate-the-need-for-cycles-and-rendering and here: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?431165-What-s-the-relevance-of-Eevee

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there is no way to reflect only Lights/Emission shaders but there is a method to prepare your scene and objects to mimic such effect.

For this example I'm using simple scene with two mesh lights, HDRI lightning and simple objects.

### Comparison:

[image: comp]

### Reflective material:

[image: material]

This is simple 'fake PBR' setting, **Layer Weight** node will allow you to make reflections be harder/softer.

### Other objects and World setup:

You will need to disable **Glossy Ray Visibility** for every object that you don't won't to be visible in your reflective material. So in this case I have disabled **Glossy** in **Cycles Settings** of each object and **Ray Visibility > Glossy** under **World settings** to 'mute' HDRI map in reflection.

[image][image]

Comment: Not a big fan of tweaking the world to make an character look correct but eliminating some reflections will be useful. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I came to terms that what I wanted to do is not doable in cycles so I worked out a solution to make the iris and pupil the part that reflects light like a lens instead. In order to accomplish this the pupil is a surface not a hole. I just created nodes to plug into the mix shader one for glossy and the other for diffuse green for the iris and black for the pupil. By doing it this way all that is reflected is greenish instead of foggy by trying to make an actual lens.

To not make the eyes look like bulging frog eyes I sunk in the iris and pupil into the eyeball while keeping the lens shape. This makes it indistinguishable from a normal eye that appears to have a lens, it even causes the edge of the lens to shine which gives it a nice look.

[image]