# Stop a material from reflecting the surroundings?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

Is it possible to have a material only respond to light, and not reflect the environment or surrounding objects? In other words, always treat everything around it as pure black, same as if you had only the object and the world color was black?

This seems like the sort of thing that should be possible with Light path, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: It's kinda workaround but check here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90481/how-do-i-limit-gloss-reflection-to-only-intense-sources-such-as-a-light-source/90502#90502

Comment: Can you provide any visual references for the result you want to achieve? I've seen OSL scripts that base their lighting only on Lamp light sources while ignoring indirect bounces... (to achieve a toon shading look.)

Comment: maybe you could render just that object into another "black world" scene and then composite it back in the full scene?