# Sunlight in Eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadowcatcher

## What I'm trying to achieve here are the same results in Eevee and Cycles

I'm using an sun and an environment texture as general setup.

[image]

The settings in Cycles are:

[image]

[image]

This is the results when rendering in EEVEE:
[image]

With these settings:
[image]

[image]

I also added and baked an irradiance volume light probe and an reflection cube map light probe for Eevee, but I am still not able to get the similar results.

Any Idea how I can achieve almost the same result will be appreciated. I know Eevee cannot be 100% Cycles, but at least 80%. I search all over the web and didn't find any useful answer.
Thx

Comment: It is hard to answer this question, as it really depends on the scene and no scene has been added. One main difference is that environment maps in EEVEE cannot cast shadows be used for high frequency lighting. But from the given information it is hard to find out what limitation you have. There are some shadows in the EEVEE scene, but they are not that hard as in Cycles,

Comment: Will be useful to upload a link to the scene? I should aware you, that is not an professional work. So don't expect too much :). But an help will be really appreciate it. I'll share only the scene with the environment, characters doesn't matter in this case.
The frame I provided to make the difference is 1441 in the scene. I also removed light probe as is doing no effect to the scene. 
here is the scene:[link](http://flagstone.ro/light_issues.rar)

Comment: You should also consider watching a good lighting tutorial for EEVEE, because setting up lights is quite a bit different there. [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/120378/23985) does quite a good job to explain the basic technical differences between Cycles and EEVEE.

Comment: Thx @metafor_set for the answer. I saw the explanations, but I'm afraid is too technical for my experience. Could you kindly sumarise what says there as I can optain what I want? Thx