# Is there a reason why my object won't render?

Tags: rendering

[image]

It looks strange and it has no noise at all, even when I move the camera. This is definitely not how it should look in rendered mode

Comment: So the issue is that the *Rendered* mode looks too good, since it doesn't show any noise? Could it be that you're using Eevee instead of Cycles (there's no pause button next to the *Rendered* mode icon)?

Comment: Ding ding ding. Thanks it was in Eevee. Isn't cycles better though for good graphics?

Comment: It depends, you can create quite amazing looking artwork with Eevee as well. If you want more physically accurate results, e.g. with global illumination effects, then Cycles is the better choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blender does render your scene properly, however it appears that *Eevee* is the currently selected render engine. This is indicated by lack of noise when moving the camera and the missing pause button when the *Rendered* mode is active.

*Eevee* was specifically build for (near) real-time rendering. It uses a technique known as [rasterization](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120372/how-does-eevee-work), which is also commonly used by game engines. *Cycles*, on the other hand, is a path tracer. The noise from the *Rendered* mode with Cycles comes from the fact that light paths are being traced from the light source into the camera. At first there are only a few samples available per pixel, which causes a grainy look. Only over time, when more samples have been calculated, it converges to the actual final image.

A good comparison of Cycles and Eevee can be found in the CGCookie article [*Cycles vs. Eevee - 15 Limitations of Real Time Rendering in Blender 2.8*](https://cgcookie.com/articles/blender-cycles-vs-eevee-15-limitations-of-real-time-rendering).