# Why does my photo not show up when importing it?

Tags: import, image

I've been following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=coyViyanlDA) on YouTube, but when I add the photo (around 0:40 in the video) the photo doesn't show up. Does anyone have an explanation or anyone have a better tutorial?

Comment: Hello! could you please provide some more information. Which type of image are you trying to use and which render engine? Maybe share your .blend file using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thank you for replying! So I am using a JPG to add as a background(?) I think and I'm using Eevee. This is the .blend file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=B07Dr8jX" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/B07Dr8jX/)

Comment: Wait, I think i'm figuring it out

Comment: photorealism can not be [achieved with eevee](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120372/how-does-eevee-work). Also there is no shadow catcher option in eevee, you would have to fake it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQJ_SBpcUQE

Comment: Related link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69832/realistic-rendering-of-mesh-together-with-image/69862#69862