# What's the difference between using eevee and cycles for video editing and rendering?

Tags: rendering, video

I understand that they are two completely different rendering engines that have their own ways of rendering the 3D world (See already answered question ["How does Eevee work"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120372/how-does-eevee-work)), but...

- Is there a difference when using blender as a video editor?
- Is there a difference in performance and/or speed when using one engine vs another for rendering videos?
- Is eevee the preferred render engine for video editing?

---

Note: This is regarding the video editing aspect of blender, NOT about the 3D aspect.

Comment: I dont thing none of those does the job, but I couldn't find any info. So, from my knowledge - there isn't a difference (what engine is set to render 3D) for VSE's image processing. BTW here how eevee works https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/120378/2214