# What's the easiest way to get as close to cycles as i can on Eevee?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

Simple  question, While tweaking with the render settings, I had noticed that compared to Cycles, Eevee looks kind of... "*flat*".

i.e.

Eevee:
[image]

Cycles (preview render at 3 samples) :

[image]

The Cycles render not only feels as if it has more "*depth*", but the shadows are softer, and overall generally feels less "cheap".

If possible, How can I get as close as possible to Cycles on Eevee?

Comment: Hello :). Could you please add some images that illustrate that *"flatness"*? There are many things that Eevee does differently.

Comment: What @ChristopherBennett said is true, but the difference between Eevee and cycles is that eevee somewhat fakes everything. It as little calculations sas possible, saving time but reducing quality. Cycles, however, does everything, making realistic but long renders. You cannot get the same quality as cycles with eevee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eevee uses approximated direct-source lighting, and Cycles uses bounced lighting. To approximate bounced lighting in eevee, you must use an **Irradiance Volume**. Additionally, you must bake indirect lighting. As you can tell from this instruction, this only works with *indirect* light sources (point lights and the like are considered direct lights in eevee - use emission materials instead.) The "softness" in the shadows of the image below are as a result of the indirect light from the *World Environment* (grey background) - not the point light.

[image: Light]

Comment: Further reading: [How does EEVEE work?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120372/how-does-eevee-work)